# Info Path Form design

Tags: infopath

how to hide the entire row in a simple (customised)table

Comment: [Comment consolidated from another question]
@Ashwini: not the repeating table. It is a custom table with 2 columns & 5 rows

Answer (score 2):

In InfoPath you can not conditionally show/hide (or otherwise programatically affect) specific rows/columns/cells in a standard table. Your best bet is to just show/hide the fields themselves that are inside the row.

If you have other text or borders and formatting that you want to hide as well you can get really close by splitting the table up and putting that row in its own section - which can be hidden using conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

check out the tutorial at

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/HA100338851033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use a control such as a repeating table, you can set up conditional formatting to hide a row that matches a condition.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding you need to use the sections or repeating table. Sections are good as we can put formatting condition on them.

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/774/3005.aspx